# ggplot2 with expression: conditional superscript the tick labels in scale_*_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript

I am trying to label the ticks on the x-axis using the following line of code:

```
scale_x_discrete("Results of the urine culture", labels=c(expression("<"~10^4~"CFU/ml"), expression(10^4~"-"~10^5~"CFU/ml"), expression(">"~10^6~"CFU/ml")))
```

The graph returns with the same value (the first in the expression, i.e. "<10^4 CFU/ml") for all three ticks. I have tried to find an answer using search but did not find the description of this problem. Could you please point out what is wrong with this code?
Thanks in advance.[image]

**Edit**

```
 DF %>%mutate(count=paste("N=", count, sep="")) %>% 
      group_by(uc.res) %>% 
      ggplot(mapping = aes(x = uc.res, y = tts.0)) + 
            geom_boxplot()+ 
            scale_x_discrete("Results of the urine culture", 
                labels=c(expression("<"~10^4~"CFU/ml"), expression(10^4~"-"~10^5~"CFU/ml"), expression(">"~10^6~"CFU/ml")))+ 
           facet_grid(~count, switch="y", space = "free_x", scales = "free_x")+ 
            theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), strip.background = element_blank(), strip.placement = "outside")
```

Comment: Could you share the rest of your code? Your snippet works with a toy example I made up, so it must be something in your previous code...

Comment: `DF %>%
  mutate(count=paste("N=", count, sep="")) %>%
  group_by(uc.res) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = uc.res, y = tts.0)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+
scale_x_discrete("Results of the urine culture", 
                   labels=c(expression("<"~10^4~"CFU/ml"), 
                            expression(10^4~"-"~10^5~"CFU/ml"), 
                            expression(">"~10^6~"CFU/ml")))+
  facet_grid(~count, switch="y", space = "free_x", scales = "free_x")+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")'

Comment: It seems that it is because of the facet_grid

Comment: @countorlok, thanks for making me the second look ))))

Answer (score 0):

Dear all problem was in the line

```
facet_grid(~count, switch="y", space = "free_x", scales = "free_x")
```

But if I remove it, I lose the number of cases in each group, that I would like to avoid.[image]

Update: Well, I have found the solution. I have removed the line with `facet_grid` and added some modifications to keep these numbers at the top of the graph. First, I tried to duplicate the x-axis using `sec_axis` to add the numbers of patients in each group on the secondary axis. But doesn't work because the x-axis was discrete and `sec_axis` works only with continuous axes. Then, I have tried simple `geom_text`, adding some modifications with `coord_cartesian` and `plot.margin`. So, the added modifications are:

```
+geom_text(aes(label=count, y=Inf), vjust=-0.5, size=5)+
coord_cartesian(clip = "off")+
theme(plot.margin = margin(20,15,15,15, unit = "pt"))
```

[image]